# Perform single submit button click event on document ready jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, onclick, form-submit

Is there a way I could perform a form submit button click on document ready only once? When I click on the submit button the form reloads and keeps clicking on that submit button again. I would like it to click once, reload the web page and stop any further clicks. Is that possible?

Comment: How about using a cookie to check whether the form has been submitted?

Comment: Sure, but you'll need server-side storage, local storage, cookie, etc.

Comment: indeed, a cookie seems to be the fastest solution in such a case.

Comment: an example without using a plugin?